# Full Width Banner that Doesn't Affect Viewport Size

Tags: html, ios, css, viewport, banner

I've been battling with this simple issue for a while and I'm looking for some help...

I'm trying to make a full width colour banner that spans the full width of the page, but doesn't in any way affect the browser viewport sizing. I want it to be visible to human eyes, but I don't want it to affect the size/location of the browser's start view or scrolling behavior... just like it's not really there.

I also want to be able to place the banner in-line in the HTML.

Here is my test page: http://www.tanatu.com/widthtest

- The Green Banner works perfectly, but it's y-location is defined in CSS (which is a pain)
- The Pink Banner is my best guess so far, and works as intended on Chrome, but not on Safari on iOS, where the viewport is skewed to one side

[Safari iOS Positioning Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB3Ea.png)

[Correct Positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AVOl.png)

I've been playing with this for months so any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated! :0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to break out of your parent container that is where your challenge is. You can do this a few ways but I think the easiest without completely changing your markup would be to use a combination of viewport width units and `calc()`

If you change these attributes on `#widthtest4` it should work:

```
#widthtest4 {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 426px);
}
```

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you so much! :0)